# How to generate an XML namespace prefix manually

Tags: webservices, wsdl2apex, xml, namespace

I have created a class by using wsdl 2 apex and consuming a wsdl file provided by BizTalk.  Previously I have consumed a similar .Net web services and have never ran into any issues.

Now when the class generates from the BizTalk wsdl and I submit something to the class BizTalk is rejecting the message since it sees the namespaces not being configured correctly.  Using WireShark I was able to see the request being sent to the BizTalk server and when I grab that request then edit it using SoapUI I can get it to work.

The only thing I change is the XML namespace to add a prefix then reference that prefix then everything works.  Is there a way of doing this by editing the files generated by the wsdl 2 apex?  I have tried doing this but haven't had any luck yet.  The XML file that is being sent to BizTalk is much larger than this file but the rest of the message is ok it's only the namespace issue that is breaking this.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  I would rather not build the file manually and to a http request but that is the route I am considering right now after running into this issue.

Request From BizTalk currently that is rejected

```
<SubmitApplication xmlns="http://xxxxx.com/xxxxxWs">
    <SubmitApplication>
        <name firstName="test" lastName="me" />  
    </SubmitApplication>
</SubmitApplication>
```

Request from SoapUI that works

```
<abc:SubmitApplication xmlns:abc="http://xxxxx.com/xxxxxWs">
    <abc:SubmitApplication>
        <name firstName="test" lastName="me" />
    </abc:SubmitApplication>
</abc:SubmitApplication>
```

Below is part of the wsdl file.

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://xxxxx.com/xxxxxWs" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://xxxxx.com/xxxxxWs">

<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://xxxxx.com/xxxxxWs">
  <s:element name="SubmitApplication">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SubmitApplication">
          <s:complexType>
            <s:sequence>
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" form="unqualified" name="applicationRequest" type="tns:OAOApplicationReq"/>
            </s:sequence>
          </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
</s:schema>
```

Comment: Seems like you are moving the `SubmitApplication` elements into the namespace defined as `abc`. The `name` element is still in the default namespace, which may differ. Can you include the applicable parts of the WSDL in the question?

Comment: Daniel - I just included some of the wsdl file in the above post.

Comment: It is a bit difficult to tell what the issue is without seeing the full WSDL. My work does produce the [FuseIT SFDC Explorer tool](http://www.fuseit.com/explorer) that can create the HTTP Requests for you from the WSDL.